# ASP.NET MVC: submit a form with input[type="file"]

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, form-submit

I was trying to submit a form with an `input[type="file"]`, here is my code:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("someaction", "somecontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FilePath, new { type = "file" })
}
```

and that's the jQuery code that was doing the job:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
            ($(this).parents('form')).submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

that was working fine, but when I try to add a hidden field, that holds an id value of my model:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("someaction", "somecontroller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FilePath, new { type = "file" })
}
```

the form doesn't want to sumbit, can anyone please help!!!

Comment: Post the controller Action this should be using (And the routes). My guess would be a mismatch in parameters there.

Comment: Define "the form doesn't want to submit".  Is the JavaScript code which binds the event handler firing?  Is the `change` event firing?  Does the form actually submit but fail in some other way?

Comment: @David When debugging the Javascript code, the `change` event is firing, but the problem is the event that submits the form: `($(this).parents('form')).submit();`. Without the hidden field, a breakpoint inside the action method within the controller affirms that the form is submitted, is that because of the `enctype` attribute ?
The only solution I have now is to pass the id value as a route value to the action